# Environment variables in Nuxt 3 with Pinia

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm trying to render env variable in Pinia store within *defineStore()* using *useRuntimeConfig()*, but the store can't use the method, throwing error:
"Nuxt instance is not unavailable".

I came up with a workaround and created a composable function where *useRuntimeConfig()* can be used and returns my environment variables. This composable is then called within the store state.

It sounds way too complicated for something what used to be as trivial as using process.env. What's the best practice in using Nuxt 3 + Pinia and env variables?

Comment: Having it in a composable sounds totally fine and is great in terms of re-usability. It's not in one place but it's mainly the goal of the whole Vue3 ecosystem right now (decouple thing independently). `process.env` was not a recommended solution for a long time already btw.

Comment: can you please share your solution's details, anyway? thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Nuxt 3 is way "harder" to do than in Nuxt 2.

Because the **Nuxt Instance** is not available in places that are not **"native" from Nuxt**, for example Pinia and it's store or any folder you create in the project that is not /server, /components, /composables, etc.

At the moment Pinia doesn't come by default in Nuxt, because of this some features like the one you are asking is not available "out of the box".
Maybe in a (near) "future" the team will incorporate it, but we don't know.

**At the moment my personal way** to solve the issue is by doing what you've done, a combination of `useRuntimeConfig()`, the `.env` file and a composable.

Remember that Nuxt 3 is a Release Candidate and Many things can change in a near future.

**Many packages wait until v1.0 release** to integrate and then document how to work with frameworks, may it will be the case with pinia.

Comment: Seems logical when you decouple things. This will probably not change anytime soon, because it's the way Composables are meant for.

Answer (score 3):

To use env vars with pinia you need set the VITE_VARIABLE in .env env file antes use import.meta.env

example to use

.env

```
VITE_BASE_URL=https://apiurl.com
```

store.js

```
const baseUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}`
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a more straight-forward way to do it.
Within Pinia's defineStore, the Nuxt app is exposed like this:

```
this.$nuxt
```

so to get env variables I can use:

```
this.$nuxt.$config.public.API_HOST
```

If I want to access it from within the plugin, then I can use:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.hook('app:created', async () => {
    console.log('Starting app with API: ', nuxtApp.$config.public.API_HOST)
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with using useNuxtApp()**:

.env

```
HOST=192.168.0.2
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {      
      host: process.env.HOST,
    },
  },
})
```

myPiniaStore.js

```js
...
const nuxt = useNuxtApp();
const host = nuxt.$config.public.host
console.log(host);
//output: 192.168.0.2
...
```

**Solution with using useRuntimeConfig()**:

.env

```
HOST=192.168.0.2
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {      
      host: process.env.HOST,
    },
  },
})
```

myPiniaStore.js

```js
...
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const host = config.public.host
console.log(host);
//output: 192.168.0.2
...
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config